# Fatal error while uploading image in Markdown. How can I solve this error?

Tags: php, github, markdown

I got this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function `superAwesomeUploadFunction()`.
I was using [this](https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor#implementing-the-image-upload)

`echo json_encode($uploadedFiles);`

I tried to use PHP normal file upload but I noticed that no binary data were transferred to upload an image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myEditor').markdownEditor({
    imageUpload: true,
    uploadPath: 'upload.php'
  });
</script>
```

I expected that the file will be uploaded successfully.

Comment: here's the file upload code <?php
if (! empty($_FILES)) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    if (superAwesomeUploadFunction($file)) {
      $uploadedFiles[] = '/img/' . urlencode($file['name']);
    }
  }
}
 
echo json_encode($uploadedFiles);
?>

Comment: The code that you are trying to run is just placeholder code from the documentation. You are supposed to write your own `superAwesomeUploadFunction` definition, or create your own function and call it. `superAwesomeUploadFunction` is just a placeholder for a function you need to define, same as how `upload.php` is a placeholder. Also, please edit your question instead of adding additional info, such as code, via comments.

Comment: Thanks JOshua T can you tell me one more thing that while i was following w3school php file uplod there is name field in html but this is not in markdown

Comment: i got it my self thank the name field is file0 by default